# Android concurrent example app

Tags: android, multithreading

Where can I find a good thread/concurrency example app for android?

I see lot of examples using AsyncTask, but on android [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) guide is stated:

> It is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent                 package such as
>   Executor,ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.

Therefore looking for a good app, that mixes all these classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i started last month to develop on android platform (but I use java since 2008) so maybe my answer could be not totally correct. I'm my apps I use async task only for very short a sync operation and for the other cases I use threads and executors combined with broadcast receivers.

For good quality documentation about concurrency I recommend you the Sun/Oracle Jdk documentation. Standard jdk band dalvik have almost the same behavior, I said almost because dalvik was written mainly for embedded systems with low computational power and low resources in general.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/

Hope this will help you

Comment: helps... still looking for an app to play/debug it.

Comment: Now I'm out of the office so can't post you some code, I'm on my tablet. From my link you can reach the Sun/Oracle concurrency tutorial. That code is really easy, well documented and fully compatible with android

Comment: If you want more depth and breadth, _Java Concurrency in Practice_ is very good.

Answer (score 0):

You can download this sample project for use of threads and AsyncTask:

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/android-hilos-asynctask.zip

The example belongs to the website www.sgoliver.net. This is a great website in Spanish and you can see many examples to learn programming on Android even if you do not know Spanish.

Hope this will help you.